# How can I fade an image along lines in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, images

I was wondering if anyone could assist with teaching me how to fade an image along lines in Illustrator (similar to the picture below).

As the lines progress a larger portion of the image is revealed.

Thanks for any help!  It is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: These aren't fading. These  are simply shapes filled with progressively thinner lines. What have you tried?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From two thick horizontal paths, create a **Blend**, 30 steps

[image: blend]

Create a Star over the blend, select the *Star* and the *Blend* and make a **Clipping Mask**

[image: Clipping Mask]

**Duplicate** the *Star* three times from right to left

[image: duplication]

Select the *Star* on the right and go to **Menu Object** > **Clipping Mask** > **Edit Contents**

- Scale the content horizontally from left to right
- Reduce the stroke thickness
- Do the same with the next two *Stars*

[image: process]

[image: result]

Comment: Hello!  THANK YOU SO MUCH!!  I followed your instructions and it worked PERFECTLY!

Comment: @FrankASchioppa Thank a little more - click accept button for an exact receipe!